# How to achieve "background-image: cover" CSS effect for dynamic images?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, background-size

When using the following CSS style, an image covers a div completely, while preserve its proportions:

```
div {
  background: url(images/plants/flower.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is that I need to generate the image URL using PHP and therefore I can't specify it in the CSS property.

I prefer not to use jQuery, JavaScript or inline CSS. The code I am after looks like this:

PHP

```
$img_url = get_img_url();
echo '<div><img src="' . $img_url . '"></div>';
```

CSS

```
 div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  size: cover;
}
```

Comment: why not only `<div style="background-image: $img_url ;">` ?

Comment: div img{width:100%; } @corre

Comment: What's dynamic about your images? Your CSS rules affect all DIVs.

Comment: current structure of the html is `<div><img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>"></div>` and I would like to keep that. This way, the PHP file maintains its purpose of defining elements and the CSS file styles them. No overlapping. @JoelAlmeida

Comment: why did someone downvote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following, without altering the html nor using other language:

PHP

```
$img_url = get_img_url();
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}

div img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP Code

```
$img_url = get_img_url();
echo '<div class='dynamic-image'><img src="' . $img_url . '"></div>';
```

and CSS

```
.dynamic-image{
position:relative;
 width: 600px;
    heigh: 200px; 
}

.dynamic-image img{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0; left:0;z-index:-1;
}
```

This code for img act like a background image action.

Comment: Will the image not be distorted here? If the image is 1000x500 and the .dynamic-image div is 500x500, the image will be 500x500?

Comment: Then let's make height: auto for img

Comment: Also if your image not sizable for cover div, backgorund-size:cover not looking good too.

Comment: by setting `height:auto;' there could be an empty space under the image inside the div if the ratio is bigger than 3:1. for example: 600x100 while the div is set to 600x200. @guvenckardas

Comment: @corre, what about just use width:100%;

Comment: I ended up just setting minimum height and width to 100%. It achieved the result that I wanted but thanks. @guvenckardas

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as background for the div, as an inline-style:

PHP:

```
$img_url = get_img_url();
echo '<div style="background-image: '.$img_url.'"></div>';
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 600px;
    heigh: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: current structure of the html is `<div><img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>"></div>` and I would like to keep that. This way, the PHP file maintains its purpose of defining elements and the CSS file styles them. No overlapping. @rblarsen